# MATCH AGAINST FULLTEXT

Tags: mysql

Как заставить обрабатывать слова короче 3-х символов? Мне понадобилось найти слово bmw, но не получилось... Операторы в тайтле вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

```
[mysqld] 
setvariable = ft_min_word_len=3
```

Спасибо Вовка

Comment: А я знал ответ...

Comment: Хочу дополнить ваш ответ: для `innodb` аналогичная настройка называется иначе - `innodb_ft_min_token_size`. Для применения изменений требуется перезапустить mysql и перестроить все fulltext индексы.